# Uninstall and reinstall a newer version of a module using admin UI

Tags: installation

I have installed a module (computed field v.3) using the "add from a url" option in the admin UI, then uninstalled it.
When trying to install the compute field v.4 I get the error "Computed Field is already present." and it can't be installed. I have cleared the cache but the problem persists.
How can I solve this? Manually delete files/folders or database entries? I have no access to ssh/drush. Thank you.

Comment: Yes it seems likely you’ll need to delete the old files that the UI downloaded for you manually. Just another reason this installation method is not recommended and probably won’t be available for much longer